# Trouble understanding a theorem, algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

That is right, I do not understand the claim. Book: William Fulton, Introduction to Algebraic Geometry, page 9, proposition 1 and for those who do not have the book my problem is that he states the following:

Let f and g be polynomials over two variables and let V(f) and V(g) be standard sets of zeros, and f and g have no common factor. Then $V(f) \bigcap V(g)$ is finite.

My trouble: Why is this set nonempty??? Any help would be great, or equivalent a book or link, reference, anything where a classification of affine subsets of $A^2$ is precisely made, because it is a very hard task, you have the case of some disjoint curves what Fulton did not consider at all.

Comment: It can be empty: if $f=x$ and $g=x-1$ (relatively prime) then $V(f)$ and $V(g)$ are parallel lines so (assuming we're working in affine space, I don't have the book to check) $V(f)\cap V(g)=\varnothing$. But why does that worry you? The empty set is finite...

Comment: This is the Bezout theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what your ambient space is, either projective or affine. In projective space the intersection will be non-empty. In affine space the intersection may be empty to take a simple example. The curves $x=0$ and $x=1$ have no point of intersection on affine plane, they are parallel lines. But the projective curves $x=0$ and $x=z$ have and intersection at infinity, $[0,1,0]$.

Answer (score 0):

If the intersection is empty, then it is finite, since the empty set is a finite set.  So you don't have to consider that possibility separately.  And in fact, it can be empty: for instance, if $f=x$ and $g=x+1$.